# how to extract words before a particular word using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, match

I need to extract the words before a particular word.

my data is.

```
data="""70MHeAhULOY8KHVLaBwcQHzAAegQICBAF">Similar</a>
</li></ol></div></div></span></div><div class="s"><div> 
 <span class="st">Mail: Consumer Advisory Service, PO Box 
 1673, MELBOURNE <em>VIC</em> 3001. Email: Click here to 
contact us via email. Any personal information you give 
 ;...kJP70MHeAhULOY8KHVLaBwcQIDAKegQIBxAE">Cached  </a>
 </li></ol></div></div></span></div><div class="s"><div> 
 <span class="st">Australia. Consumer Advisory Service 
 GPO Box 
1673. MELBOURNE, <em>VIC</em>, 3001. AUSTRALIA. New Zealand. 
Cadbury Freepost 577. PO Box 890. Dunedin&nbsp;...</span>
```

I am trying to extract the word before `'VIC'`

My expected output is `['1673, MELBOURNE','1673. MELBOURNE,']` as we have two matches in my data

my code:
`re.find_all(r"\*+\s(\*) <em> vic",data)`

but not working

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: updated with my code, pls check

Comment: You need to use `beautifulsoup` lib to parse HTML.

Comment: no, i am trying to extract informations using regex. no need a soup object

Comment: Will all your data be in this pattern `Box 1673, MELBOURNE <em>VIC</em> 3001. ` ? With the text Box at the start?

Comment: "the word before VIC" would be this `(\w+)\W*<em>VIC`, but what you claim to want to match is not quite that

Comment: exactly how many words before VIC do you want to extract ? 2?

Comment: yes I want to extract the previous two words before 'VIC'

Comment: @sweaver2112 your code not matching ,pls check https://regex101.com/r/bhtcAA/2

Comment: Try `([a-z,0-9A-Z.]+)\s([a-z,0-9A-Z.]+)\s<em>VIC`

Comment: You can try `Box\s*(\d*)[,\.]?(.*)[,\s]?<em>VIC`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this regex for extracting exactly two words before *VIC*,

```
\s+([^\s]+?\s+[^\s]+?)\s*<em>VIC<\/em>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVbmKG/1)

Here is a python sample code for same,

```
import re
data='70MHeAhULOY8KHVLaBwcQHzAAegQICBAF">Similar</a></li></ol></div></div></span></div><div class="s"><div>  <span class="st">Mail: Consumer Advisory Service, PO Box  1673, MELBOURNE <em>VIC</em> 3001. Email: Click here to contact us via email. Any personal information you give  ;...kJP70MHeAhULOY8KHVLaBwcQIDAKegQIBxAE">Cached  </a> </li></ol></div></div></span></div><div class="s"><div>  <span class="st">Australia. Consumer Advisory Service  GPO Box 1673. MELBOURNE, <em>VIC</em>, 3001. AUSTRALIA. New Zealand. Cadbury Freepost 577. PO Box 890. Dunedin&nbsp;...</span>'
d = re.findall(r"\s+([^\s]+?\s+[^\s]+?)\s*<em>VIC<\/em>",data)
print(d)
```

This gives following output,

```
['1673, MELBOURNE', '1673. MELBOURNE,']
```

Comment: works good, how to extract only one word before vic

Comment: For extracting just one word, you can use this \s+([^\s]+?)\s*<em>VIC<\/em>